# How to get values from MySql Database based on SelectBox value - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to get values in selectbox-2 with change in SelectBox-1 values

Like if SelectBox-1 value is 'Physics' then I want to get values in Selectbox-2 from table-1 and If value is 'chemistry' I want to get values from table-2

Here's my code

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
$db = mysqli_select_db($con,"skans");
$getsubject=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM subjects");
$getlist1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT batch FROM batchlist");
$getlist2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT batch1 FROM batchlist");
?>
```

Html code

```
<html>
<body>

<table width="500" align="center" >
    <tr>
    <td><span> Subject:</span></td>
    <td>
     <select id="subjects">
        <option value="none" selected >----Select ----</option>
       <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getsubjects))
            {
            ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo($row['subjects'])?>" >
                <?php echo($row['subjects']) ?>
            </option>
            <?php
            }               
        ?>
     </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

<!--////// Select Box 2 - I want to get values in this selectbox based on first ///////-->

<tr id="batch">
    <td><span> Batch:</span></td>
    <td>
     <select>
       <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getbatch))
            {
            ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo($row['batch1'])?>" >
                <?php echo($row['batch1']) ?>
            </option>
            <?php
            }               
        ?>
     </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
<hr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please start by understanding how `<form>`'s work in HTML and PHP http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php Without a `<form>` nothing is going to be transmitted between your page and a PHP Script

Comment: You can do this with AJAX or based on your actual approach you could create both of the selects and hide/ show them with Javascript based on the values from the first select. On this page http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp you can see almost what you are looking for, except that, based on the first select it fetches one distinct row instead of multiple rows.

Comment: Don't You like to use XHR to fetch data? Or even $_GET variable?

Comment: sir you can use DataTable library for filtration of your data [link](https://datatables.net)

Comment: What about If statement.

Comment: @RiggsFolly don't write all code but give me some idea. or only php statement